# I can't find JUnit classes in specified packages in Project Explorer in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ide, junit-jupiter

I can't find generated JUnit test classes in project(and package) explorer packages. Although they can be found in source folder(.apt_generated_tests), but not in a specified package (com/example/testing/requests/getRequests) [But you can see here that package is written in the test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZLQ.png)

I have tried to refresh project(packages, folders), rebuild project, cleaned project several times. I also tried to restart project, I manually tried to close project and reopen, deleted from workspace and imported again. I can still write code and run unit tests in the test class, but can#t access them in packages. [only one file is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOJyk.png)

Comment: Did you already add the location where the tests are as a source folder?

Comment: Is source folder and package the same thing? I specified different pathes as source folder and package (source folder: ProjectName/.apt_generated_classes and package: /requests/getRequests) and tests are in source folder

Comment: A source folder and a package is not the same thing. Everything starting with  `.` like `.apt_generated_classes` will be hidden by default. Click the filter icon and uncheck _.* resources_ to make `.apt_generated_classes` visible (according to the name I would guess it's an output folder containing .class files, not a source folder with .java files).